# Modeling fixed- effects without interaction terms

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, fixed-effects-model

I'm trying to model a linear mixed effects model but whenever I tried to model interaction terms my model gives error about convergence. Although I tried to increase the number of iterations as possible solution I could not achieve to model interactions either. What are your suggestions about this?

With only main effects, my code works fine but ı need to interpret the interaction terms as well. Also I 'm not quite sure is it appropriate to model the fixed effects with only main effects, without interaction?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post some code and/or the output?

Comment: How many samples and independent variables do you have?  Did you initially include all first order interactions?

Comment: I have 3 independent variables, age, gender and unit (unit has 6 categories). I only include significant  first order interactions to the model.